# What are useful options for gcc/g++?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, g++

It is almost common knowledge that one should always compile with `-Wall`.

What other useful options are you using when compiling with `gcc`/`g++`?

Comment: Define "useful". I quite like -fdump-rtl-all-details, but I doubt you do.

Comment: Hm, what I mean is something that most of us should have in their shell configuration because it's so valuable for day-to-day use.

Comment: @ams: really, you like the `-fdump-*`things? Then MELT extensions for GCC should interest you!!!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I like the -fdump-* for debugging GCC itself. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want `-Wextra` in addition of `-Wall`.

When debugging your program, `-g` is needed by `gdb`.

<sup>and GCC accepts both `-g` and `-O` if you really want</sup>

At last, recent versions of GCC (i.e. 4.6 or the 4.7 snapshot) gives better warnings than older ones.

You could use `-pedantic` and restrict yourself to some standard, avoiding GNU extensions.
I love GNU extensions so I don't want to avoid them.

So I use `-std=gnu99` for C code, and `-std=gnu0x` or `-std=gnu11` for C++11 code because I like extensions.

And you might consider using or even developing a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension for your own specific needs.

Comment: I just found `-Wshadow` very useful. Unfortunately, it is not enabled by `-Wall` or even `-Wextra`.